# Eigenvalue relation with conjugated variable

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, linear-transformations, physics

I am currently facing a problem where I would like to find, for a given complex square matrix $H$, the vectors $x$ and values $\lambda$ satisfying the "eigen-relationship" like

$$Hx=\lambda \overline{x}$$

Does this equation have a name ? Is there a theory on this ? Can it be linked to a more traditionnal problem in some way ?

For the background, the matrix $H$ models the mode coupling for electromagnetic wave scattering in a given system. A solution to the above equation is a mode combination such that the propagated wave is the same as the incoming one but in the reverse direction (up to a multiplicative factor).

Thank you for any reference or help you may provide.

Answer (score 2):

This is a first step to answering your question. Separate real and imaginary parts. Write $H=A+iB$, $\lambda=\mu+i\nu$, and a solution $z=x+iy$. Then we get (if I haven't made a sloppy error)
\begin{align*}
Ax-By &= \mu x - \nu y \\
Bx+Ay &= \nu x - \mu y.
\end{align*}
So this turns into an interesting question of finding values $\mu$ and $\nu$ so that the matrix
$$\left[\begin{array}c A-\mu I & -B+\nu I \\ B-\nu I & A+\mu I \end{array}\right]$$
is singular. (But computing the determinant of this matrix will be difficult, unless $A$ and $B$ happen to commute.) The nullspace of that matrix will then give you a nontrivial solution of your original problem.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This question does not seem so appealing for this community unfortunately. I have thought of this kind of separation (should have told that in the question but actually I have been thinking about this for several days so I forgot) but did not went through the final "singular matrix" problem when I got to that coupled system of equation that seemed harder than the first one. That might be a nice first step to investigate further. You have my upvote for that and I might come back here at some point to make an update.

Comment: The presence of the conjugate indicates that this is not a problem in complex linear algebra, so offhand I don’t see what else to try.

Comment: Well I am also open to numerical methods, I think I could adapt a power iteration method. But I first wanted to try full theoretical approaches. As you indicate, the conjugate operation induces a non-linearity, hence the lack of interest I guess. Unfortunately for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I post this as a comment to Ted's post, rather than just posting the final result as a comment so that I can show all my work in case I've made a mistake. From what I have below, it seems that the upper right should be $-B-I\nu$ instead of $-B+I\nu$.
$$\newcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}\newcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}
\overbrace{(A+iB)}^H\overbrace{\,(x+iy)\,}^z=\overbrace{\,(\mu+i\nu)\,}^\lambda\overbrace{\,(x-iy)\,}^{\bar z}\tag1
$$
$$
\overbrace{(Ax-By)}^{\Re(Hz)}+i\overbrace{(Bx+Ay)}^{\Im(Hz)}=\overbrace{(\mu x+\nu y)}^{\Re(\lambda\bar z)}+i\overbrace{(\nu x-\mu y)}^{\Im(\lambda\bar z)}\tag2
$$
Putting the real part on top and the imaginary part on the bottom, we get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}A&-B\\B&A\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\mu&\nu\\\nu&-\mu\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\tag3
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}A-I\mu&-B-I\nu\\B-I\nu&A+I\mu\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=0\tag4
$$

Comment: Actually I have done the same mistake as him when I tried prior to asking this question. Thank you for that contribution.

Comment: Yup, I suspected a sloppy error. Although the asymmetry wasn’t shocking. Now, if $A$ and $B$ commute, the singularity condition becomes $\det(A^2+B^2) = \mu^2-\nu^2$ (I think).